# SSIS: How to use a column from a flat file to determine a value from a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, csv, ssis, flat

I'm pretty newbie in SSIS, so please excuse my easy question. I was not able to find the answer in SO.

I have the following CSV file, imported as a flat file source:

```
Date         |  Value
01/01/1900   |  250
```

And a MySQL table 'Calendar' like this:

```
Date         |  Date_id
01/01/1900   |  1
```

So basically, what I need is to grab that `Date` column from the CSV file and insert that date into another table with the CSV's value as well, but not the date perse, but the matching id, for example:

```
Date_id         |  Value
1               |  250
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You want to add Lookup Component between your source and destination.

Comment: But how do you add a lookup component if it asks for a OLE DB Connection? (i'm using ODBC to connect to MySQL, and CherryCity's OLE DB component is not permitted as I don't have the license).

Comment: Option 1) Cache Connection Manager. Option 2, Merge Join (sort your inputs)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a closer look at it and report back my findings.